# Creating a Velocity template for Dynamic Data List (Liferay 6.2)

Tags: templates, liferay, velocity, freemarker, datalist

I'm currently working with liferay 6.2 but i'm having problems to create a Display Template for a Dynamic data list. I'm trying to follow this guide:

https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/make-it-pretty-creating-custom-displays#display-templates

But the FreeMarker example doesn't work. I'm trying to create a template in Velocity (since i have more knoledge than FreeMarker):

My code so far is:

```
<h1>Title</h1>

#set($DDLRecordLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.service.DDLRecordLocalService"))
#set ($records = $DDLRecordLocalService.getRecords("TitoloDeEmprego"))

#if(!$records.isEmpty())
    <h1>$records.getFieldValue("TitoloDeEmprego")</h1>
#end
```

but i can't get anything from $records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to allow your Freemarker/Velocity template to access *serviceLocator* variable. In order to do this, you need to put the following line in your *portal-ext.properties*:

```
# Freemarker template settings
freemarker.engine.restricted.variables=
```

I think this is the cause, but if you have any other problems, this is simple Freemarker DDL Display Template that works for me:

```
<#assign DDLRecordLocalService = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.service.DDLRecordLocalService")>
<#assign records = DDLRecordLocalService.getRecords(reserved_record_set_id)>

<#if records?has_content>
    <ul>
        <#list records as cur_record>
            <li>
                <a href="${ddmUtil.getDisplayFieldValue(themeDisplay, cur_record.getFieldValue("someLinkFieldName", locale), cur_record.getFieldType("someLinkFieldName"))}">
                    <img src="${ddmUtil.getDisplayFieldValue(themeDisplay, cur_record.getFieldValue("someImageFieldName", locale), cur_record.getFieldType("someImageFieldName"))}" />
                </a>
            </li>
        </#list>
    </ul>
</#if>
```

Comment: In my portal.properties is already the line "freemarker.engine.restricted.variables= serviceLocator". I tryed the code template you sugest but it don't work either, it gaves me an error when it comes to read "service locator

Comment: Yes, because there should be nothing after '=' sign, and you still have the word 'servicelocator'

Comment: And you should do the same for velocity if you still want to use it, set "velocity.engine.restricted.variables="

Comment: I see, i didn't understand at first how that line actually works. Now works perfectly fine. Thank you very much